# How to handle event for HTML tags defined within XML view?

Tags: javascript, html, sapui5

I am trying to combine UI5 `XMLView` and standard HTML elements. In XML view, we can use `press=".onSomething"` attribute and `onSomething: function(){}` in the controller. But how to handle pure HTML events? Here is my code:

```xml
<mvc:View controllerName="banalyzer.controller.App" 
  xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
  xmlns="sap.m"
  xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <!-- ... -->
    <html:ul class="tab">
      <html:li>
        <html:a href="#" onclick="onBud()">Budget Analyzer</html:a>
      </html:li>
      <html:li>
        <html:a href="#" onclick="spend()">Spend Analyzer</html:a>
      </html:li>
    </html:ul>
  <!-- ... -->
</mvc:View>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The HTML elements are copied by the XMLView into the page on rendering of the View. As they are not UI5 controls but HTML DOM elements, the events and properties will not be processed. So the code in your `onclick` events will be copied untouched to the output page.

When the user clicks on such a link, the code will be executed in the global window context. There is no easy way to find the UI5 View instance that has rendered the link and its Controller instance where your want to call a method.

The easiest way to attach HTML events to a controller method would be to give the HTML elements an `id` and bind the events in your controller's `onAfterRendering` hook:

```html
<!-- In the View definition -->
<html:a xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" id="myLink" href="#">My Link</html:a>
```

```js
{ // Controller
  onBeforeRendering: function() {
    // Remove the exiting event handler to prevent double-registration next time
    if (this._abortController && typeof this._abortController.abort === "function") {
      this._abortController.abort(); // deregisters the handler
    }
  },

  onAfterRendering: function() {
    this._abortController = new AbortController();
    const htmlElement = document.getElementById(this.createId("myLink"));
    htmlElement.addEventListener("click", this.onClick.bind(this), {
      signal: this._abortController.signal // making the handler removable
    });
  },

  onClick: function() {
    alert("Clicked!");
  },
}
```

Example on [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/ziyocah/edit?js,output).

---

About the `AbortController`, see ["Add an abortable listener"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#add_a_abortable_listener) from MDN.